# Apache Virtual Host Configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, virtualhost

I have been searching the internet for an hour now, and I was hoping for a quick hint here so that I could solve my problem a wee bit faster.

My virtual server is so far only accessible through an IP address, no DNS entry yet, and so far none needed either.

The problem I have is with Apache2, the virtual hosts are puzzling me.

What I need is:

Access to my project (based on Symfony2) from the outside with the IP address

Access to my project from localhost

What I have got:

Access from the outside results in rendering the websites in /var/www/vhosts/htdocs/default, while from the inside results in rendering the websites in /var/www.
Why the difference?

What is a recommended configuration for my use case?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the first parameter after the `<VirtualHost` part of your Apache config is `127.0.0.1`.  This will mean that when you request a website on the loopback interface you hit one vhost and on any other interface you get a different vhost.

The output of `apache2ctl -S` will probably tell you what is going on.

Comment: In /etc/apache2/sites-available I have a default VirtualHost configuration which is using /var/www as DocumentRoot; thus I don't understand how it can get to /var/www/vhosts

Comment: Post your httpd.conf and any virtual host config files (redact any sensitive information, shouldn't be much to begin with). We'll have a much better chance of helping you then.

Comment: My httpd.conf is empty, the only file I have is the default file in /etc/apache2/sites-available. The content:

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
# content related to CGI
</VirtualHost>
Thanks :)!

Comment: It's probably best to post that in your question where you can format it properly.  Anyway, it seems my first guess was wrong.  The next thing I would suggest is recursively grepping for the two different document roots you identified in your config directory:  `grep -r DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/` or ` grep -r "/var/www/vhosts/htdocs/default" /etc/apache2/`.

Comment: Yes, true, the formatting is not the best - sorry for that. I grep'd the search terms and had no hits for the second command. Is there any implicit logic that Apache2 will resolve remote access to vhosts default directory, instead of the /var/www directory?

Comment: "I" solved it, there was an interference caused by the pre-installed Plesk application. Now it is working fine. I interpreted the output of apache2ctl -S in a wrong way at first, but then I took a look at it again and noticed what was going on. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if you cant use hostname for virtual host, maybe you should use different port than 80 ?
ex

```
 <VirtualHost 10.1.1.10:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ...
    </VirtualHost>
```